# Get a byte size of single extrinsic/transaction

Tags: extrinsic, block

I am trying to calculate how many transactions can fit into a single block. I have a block limit of 5mb. How can i learn the byte size of a single submitted transaction so i can estimate how many transactions can fit into a single block. Is there a way to do it from a polkadot js api?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In polkadot-js, for any `Codec` object (the base of any object returned in the API), there is an `.encodedLength` getter that returns the length. So assuming the extrinsic is signed, `tx.encodedLength` will have the information.

(Unsigned transactions, since they are missing the signature, etc. info, would be shorter)

Comment: It worked! Thank you!